# Removing items based on two lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, asp.net-mvc-4, removeall

I have two lists, one is list of strings and other one is a list of complex type called "ItemTransactions".

The first list contains list of ItemID's, and based on that first list, wherever the ItemID in "ItemTransactinos" list occurs, it has to be removed...

Doing it the traditional way like following is very slow of both lists are large:

```
foreach (var item in ItemIDs) // ItemIDs is lsit of strings 
{
  itemTransactions.Remove(/*remove*/); // 1 itemID can occur multiple times in this list... So I would like to remove all items in this collections that correspond 1 ItemID at once if possible?
}
```

Can someone help me out with this one ?

P.S. The ItemTransactions collections contains property called "ItemID' which is type of string as well... Just to note that

Comment: So the issue is performance and you're looking for suggestions on how to optimise? You might want to include a MVCE and an example dataset.

Comment: @ChrisPickford Yes and also basically how to even remove multple transactions belonging to 1 ItemID  at once ... I don't have idea how it can be done in an efficient manner  since both lists can be quite large?

Comment: Cant you just do something based on `ItemList.Where(i => !StringList.Contains(i.ItemID)`?

Comment: @nalka the end product needs to be the list (complex type) without all itemids from the ItemID list :D

Comment: @nalka but good point :D

Comment: @nalka can you hang on i will try this solution to see if it will work ...

Comment: Is the data coming from a DBMS? If so I'd suggest doing this operation at that level using appropriate indexes instead of looping in memory.

Comment: @nalka no the lists are being compared in memory

Comment: Well my code + `.ToList()` does this doesnt it?

Comment: @nalka it looks like so :D

Comment: So are you fine with it or need a better answer?  @User987

Comment: @nalka i have to first test it lolz :D

Comment: @nalka but it looks like a decent solution.. Not sure on how it'll work on large lists...

Comment: Tag me if you need a better answer otherwise let me know it's working alright and i'll post an answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187573/discussion-between-user987-and-nalka).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`RemoveAll`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.removeall?view=netframework-4.7.2):

```
itemTransactions.RemoveAll(i => ItemIDs.Contains(i.ItemID));
```

Not sure if this is faster or not, but it's a bit more concise and explicit. You'll ultimately have to test different options to see which code performs better for you.

Comment: If `ItemIDs` is a long list, convert it to a `HashSet<string>` first. This will also improve speed.

Comment: This wont be good this method being defined on lists and not on iqueryable (according to the link you sent), it will filter in memory not in the database

Comment: @nalka I don't see anywhere in OPs question where `IQueryable` or anything to do with a database is mentioned

Comment: He mentionned ID's which is what made me think of it but my comment is relevant anyways as other people than User987 may check this answer and use it even if they arent in the exact same context than User987

Answer (score 0):

```
ItemList.Where(item => !StringList.Contains(item.ItemID);
```

Will work alright for what you're looking for.

Comment: If ItemIDs is a long in-memory list, convert it to a HashSet<string> first (Or use a HashSet from the start). This will also improve speed.